# Unable to install babel on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, npm-install

I'm trying to learn `ReactJS` and it needed me to install `babel` and few other loaders of `babel`.

I tried installing babel using the command `npm install babel`. But running this command gave me errors. Here is the log of my terminal. http://pastebin.com/avEP2tb3

How do I resolve the above error and install babel.

I tried searching for solutions on Internet but couldn't find one.

Comment: If you are using babel 6, you should be installing `babel-cli` not `babel` which doesn't do anything anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theses are all warning. A `node_modules/` folder should've been created in your project directory, with babel.